# Ошибка :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android

При запуске приложения получаю следующую ошибку:

:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>
> Task :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\91.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\92.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\93.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\104.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\105.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\106.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\107.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\112.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\114.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\131.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\181.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\182.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\183.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\184.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\185.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\186.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\187.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\188.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\189.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\209.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\210.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\211.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\212.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\213.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\214.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\215.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\216.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\217.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\218.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\219.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\220.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\221.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\222.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\223.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\224.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\225.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\226.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\227.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\228.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\231.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\233.jar,
>     H:\Android\Dictionary\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\234.jar

build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dictionary"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0'
}
```

Кто-нибудь знает, что ее вызывает и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в `gradle.properties` прописать

```
android.enableJetifier=true 
android.useAndroidX=true
```

И версию gradle поднять до 3.2.0 или выше.
О миграции к Android X посмотрите [здесь](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).
Также нужно обновить android studio к выше 3.2

Comment: Спасибо, но это не помогло

Comment: @RedBro вы мигрировали проект к androidX через android studio?

Comment: @RedBro какая у вас версия android studio?

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но где ее найти? Я использую андроид студию в IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: @RedBro не знаю, никогда не работал с android в intelliJ idea)
советую вам перейти в android studio для разработки под android

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался. Проблема оказалась в сторонней библиотеке, я убрал это  implementation 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0' и все заработало. Но видимо придется искать другой способ создания таблицы с динамическим заполнением, может вы знаете как лучше создать такую таблицу?

Comment: @RedBro это означает, что та библиотека не поддерживает androidX.
Я бы делал не таблицей, а через `RecyclerView`
https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview